# Pytorch and Scikit-Learn - Labels starting from 0 or 1

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pytorch

For both Pytorch and Scikit-Learn, is there any requirement for labels for start from 0 all the way to 1, 2, 3, number of classes? Or can I have labels start from 1, for example?

This is just a matter of having to apply a label encoder manually to the dataset or not.